# How to use an Jquery object from external file in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am relatively new to frond-end.

I was wondering how I can use an jquery object returned from external link.

For example, a js file on this location(https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-en-NZ.js) returns 'datepicker.regional[ "en-NZ" ];' object like below

```
( function( factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( [ "../widgets/datepicker" ], factory );
    } else {

        // Browser globals
        factory( jQuery.datepicker );
    }
}( function( datepicker ) {

datepicker.regional[ "en-NZ" ] = {
    closeText: "Done",
    prevText: "Prev",
    nextText: "Next",};
datepicker.setDefaults( datepicker.regional[ "en-NZ" ] );

return datepicker.regional[ "en-NZ" ];
```

I import this js file to main html file and embed it in head tag.

```
<script src="path/datepicker-en-NZ.js"></script>
```

Now I need use the returned object which is **datepicker.regional["en-NZ"]**. 
How can I use this object in main html file?

Answer (score 0):

Check example code in [project](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/demos/datepicker/default.html):

1. I would suggest you add Bootstrap.js in your html
2. You need to add input control in your html file i.e. id = myDate
3. Bind it with datepicker

> $( "#myDate" ).datepicker();

Comment: Can you share code or html so I would check why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a demo on the jQueryUI website that provides some insight into how to use their datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

I believe the Javascript in the source code provided is the important bit:

```
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

My understanding is that you need to create a Datepicker object and bind it to an `<input>` using its ID.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the new(for me) concept.

This is called Factory function.

The definition of Factory function is **A function that returns an object.**

In my case, I was trying to use an object created from factory function which was **datepicker.regional[ "en-NZ" ]**.

So I could call and use this object in main html file by adding **$.** before the name of object.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker($.datepicker.regional[ "zh-CN" ] );
});
</script>
```

And it was also important to add document.ready part unless it won't start kicking in.